# How to fix Array Substitution Error on Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an error on array substitution.

```
way=[[0]*4]*2
arri=[1]*4
for i in range(0,2):
    arri[i]=0
    way[i]=arri
    print(way)
```

I thought that

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

will be printed on the console, but actually:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

This got printed on console.

When I fix `way[i]` to `way[1]`,

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

This got printed.

What's the point I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `way=[[0]*4]*2` gives you two references pointing to the same list `[0, 0, 0, 0]`, which can be proved by their identical id:

```
In [4]: way=[[0]*4]*2
In [5]: way
Out[5]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
In [6]: way[0][0] = 1
In [7]: way
Out[7]: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
In [8]: id(way[0])
Out[8]: 39479992
In [9]: id(way[1])
Out[9]: 39479992
```

You may use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create your lists like `way = [[0]*4 for i in range(2)]`

You may ask why `[0]*4` gives you a normal `[0, 0, 0, 0]`:

```
In [16]: way
Out[16]: [0, 0, 0, 0]
In [17]: way[0] = 1
In [18]: way
Out[18]: [1, 0, 0, 0]  # not [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

That's because `0` is an integer, which is of an immutable type `int`, and `[0, 0, 0, 0]` is of a mutable type `list`. You can see [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) to get more information.